# 2 player tictactoe pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I want to distinguish 2 players in a tictactoe game in pygame. The "click" function is an (x,y) co-ordinate of where the user clicked and in they clicked in a certain place i'd update the shape. Also the "current game" is just an array that holds the state of the current game.

The logic seems correct, but the code will not run, and just bugs when the GUI opens.

```
        i=1
        while i<10:
            if p1==True and p2 == False:
                #1st row
                if  click[0]<=250 and click[0]>=100 and click[1]<=250 and click[1]>=100:
                    current_game[0][0] = "X"
                    i+=1
                    p2=True
                    p1=False

                if  click[0]<=550 and click[0]>=250 and click[1]<=250 and click[1]>=100:
                    current_game[0][1] = "X"
                    i += 1
                    p2=True
                    p1 = False

                if  click[0]<=700 and click[0]>=550 and click[1]<=250 and click[1]>=100:
                    current_game[0][2] = "X"
                    i += 1
                    p2=True
                    p1 = False

                #2nd row
                if  click[0]<=250 and click[0]>=100 and click[1]<= 550and click[1]>=250:
                    current_game[1][0] = "X"
                    i += 1
                    p2=True
                    p1 = False

                if  click[0]<=550 and click[0]>=250 and click[1]<=550 and click[1]>=250:
                    current_game[1][1] = "X"
                    i += 1
                    p2=True
                    p1 = False

                if  click[0] <= 700 and click[0] >= 550 and click[1] <= 550 and click[1] >= 250:
                    current_game[1][2] = "X"
                    i += 1
                    p2=True
                    p1 = False

                #3rd row
                if click[0]<=250 and click[0]>=100 and click[1]<= 700and click[1]>=550:
                    current_game[2][0] = "X"
                    i += 1
                    p2=True
                    p1 = False

                if  click[0] <= 550 and click[0] >= 250 and click[1] <= 700 and click[1] >= 550:
                    current_game[2][1] = "X"
                    i += 1
                    p2=True
                    p1 = False

                if  click[0] <= 700 and click[0] >= 550 and click[1] <= 700 and click[1] >= 550:
                    current_game[2][2] = "X"
                    i += 1
                    p2=True
                    p1 = False



            if p2==True and p1==False:
                # 1st row
                if  click[0] <= 250 and click[0] >= 100 and click[1] <= 250 and click[1] >= 100:
                    current_game[0][0] = "o"
                    i += 1
                    p1 = True
                    p2 = False

                if  click[0] <= 550 and click[0] >= 250 and click[1] <= 250 and click[1] >= 100:
                    current_game[0][1] = "o"
                    i += 1
                    p1 = True
                    p2 = False

                if  click[0] <= 700 and click[0] >= 550 and click[1] <= 250 and click[1] >= 100:
                    current_game[0][2] = "o"
                    i += 1
                    p1 = True
                    p2 = False


                # 2nd row
                if  click[0] <= 250 and click[0] >= 100 and click[1] <= 550 and click[1] >= 250:
                    current_game[1][0] = "o"
                    i += 1
                    p1 = True
                    p2 = False
                if  click[0] <= 550 and click[0] >= 250 and click[1] <= 550 and click[1] >= 250:
                    current_game[1][1] = "o"
                    i += 1
                    p1 = True
                    p2 = False

                if  click[0] <= 700 and click[0] >= 550 and click[1] <= 550 and click[1] >= 250:
                    current_game[1][2] = "o"
                    i += 1
                    p1 = True
                    p2 = False

                # 3rd row
                if click[0] <= 250 and click[0] >= 100 and click[1] <= 700 and click[1] >= 550:
                    current_game[2][0] = "o"
                    i += 1
                    p1 = True
                    p2 = False

                if  click[0] <= 550 and click[0] >= 250 and click[1] <= 700 and click[1] >= 550:
                    current_game[2][1] = "o"
                    i += 1
                    p1 = True
                    p2 = False

                if  click[0] <= 700 and click[0] >= 550 and click[1] <= 700 and click[1] >= 550:
                    current_game[2][2] = "o"
                    i += 1
                    p1 = True
                    p2 = False
```

Comment: Can you please add a technical description of the error, "just bugs" is not good enough.  Please include the actual error text, or a reasonable description of the failure.

Comment: First, look at Kingsley's comment, second, there are much more code effecnt ways to do this, and it is probaly some typo in all those if statement. Try using a nested loop to figure out the mouse x and y, like this:  You have two loops (i, j), i nested inside the j. You check if click[0] > boxSize*i + xOffset, and the same with Y. Then make sure click[0] < boxSize*(i+1) + xOffset, and again then you do the same as y. Boom, you've replaced all that code with something like 10 lines.

Comment: did my answer resolve the issue?

Answer (score 2):

If you didn't omit code within the `while` loop, then you can start with:

```
while i<10:
    # this line seems to be missing
    click = somefunction_that_waits_for_click_and_returns_coordinates()
    ...
```

your current code never updates the values of `click`. Therfore `clickp[0]` and `click[1]` will never change values